# Why Mysql ORDER BY is not working with GROUP BY keyword?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting last 5 `view_id` from mysql table called `history`. Using this `view_id` I am getting `family_name`, `company_name` from `contact_details` and `company` table.

Now I want to show `family_name` as Ascending order but somehow its not showing the `family_name` as Ascending order !

**Here is my code :**

```
$getViewID = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT view_id, hid, is_save FROM history WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND mark_as = 1 GROUP BY view_id LIMIT 5 ");

if( mysqli_num_rows($getViewID) ) {    

   while( $fetchViewId = mysqli_fetch_array($getViewID) ) {
      $viewid = (int) $fetchViewId['view_id'];
      $hid = (int) $fetchViewId['hid'];
      $is_save = (int) $fetchViewId['is_save'];

      $getDetails = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cd.cdid, cd.family_name, company.company_name FROM contact_details AS cd LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid WHERE cd.cdid = '$viewid' ORDER BY cd.family_name ASC ");            
      if(mysqli_num_rows($getDetails) > 0 ) {
         while($resDetail = mysqli_fetch_array($getDetails)) {
            $cdid = (int) $resDetail['cdid'];         
            $family_name = stripcslashes($resDetail['family_name']);       
            $family_name = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $family_name);
            $company = stripcslashes($resDetail['company_name']);

            if (strlen($family_name) >= 10) {
               $family_name =  substr($family_name, 0, 8);
            }
            if(strlen($company) >= 15) {
                 $company =  substr($company, 0, 14);
            }
            $url_link = "{$url}index.php?redcdid=$cdid";
            if($is_save == 1) {
               $checked = 'checked = "checked"';
            } else {
               $checked = '';
            }
            echo "<li><a href='$url_link'>&nbsp;&nbsp;$family_name - $company </a> <input $checked type='checkbox' name='save_history' class='data_save' data-saveid='$viewid' data-hid='$hid'></li>";
         }                  
      } // contact end here
   }
   echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Comment: Show us your current output.  I'd bet on the query or your expectation being wrong over an actual problem with MySQL.

Comment: It's showing Y, M, H, A as first family name order.

Comment: I see, you're querying inside the loop...it's even worse than that you don't use prepared statements. `view_id` is a link between `contact_details`  and `history` tables. Think about additional join